# Get a pattern in a string starts and ends with a specific character

Tags: linux, shell

I am working on shell script and I want to get a pattern in a string starts and ends with a specific character. As much as I can do was:

```
a=`grep -oh ^\/ $1`
grep -oh \'$ $a
```

I know that `grep -oh` command finds a word in a file and prints it so I tried to find the words starts with `/` and ends with `'`.
But it still finds words, but I need patterns to find, like if `/bin/ls'dir` is the string, I have to get /bin/ls. Also like this I can not suppress `'` character at the end.

How could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl regular expressions are handy with the lookahead assertions:

```
str="like if /bin/ls'dir is the string, I have to get /bin/ls. "
grep -oP "/.*?(?=')" <<< "$str"
```

```
/bin/ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a list, not with text:

```
 #!/bin/bash
echo "/bin/ls'dir"|awk -F\' '{print "dir: "$1"  end: "$NF}'
```